# End = ' ' in nested loop

Tags: python

I just started python few days ago, and didn't really understand **end =' '** in nested loop. Can anybody explain me this

```
count=0
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print (count, end='')
    count +=1
    print()
```

Comment: What does this have to do with (nested) loops?

Answer (score 2):

`''` is the "empty string" (e.g. nothing).  The "end" parameter is what gets printed after the preceding set of variables.  The default value of "end" is the newline (i.e. subsequent print statements will begin on a new line).  By specifying `''`, the loop above will literally print out

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

with each inner loop result on a single line.  Without the `end=''` param, it would get printed out as:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
...
9
9
```

The final `print()` at the end of the inner loop, just prints a new line.

Answer (score 0):

End is print function keyword argument. The default value of `end` is `\n` meaning that after the `print` statement it will print a new line. If you redefine `end`, `print` will output your redefined value after using.

```
print("123", end="=")
#prints '123='
```

`''` means empty string, so, you wil get output with no delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `end` is `\n` meaning that after the print statement it will print a new line. So simply stated end is what you want to be printed after the print statement has been executed,

prints an according Count value and stays in the same line. If you left out the `end=''` each time a newline would be printed

Answer (score -1):

We learn everything by doing, So lets suppose we remove that end="" at the end of the print function. So you code will look like this

```
    count=0
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print (count)
    count +=1
    print()
```

and the output will be as

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
...
```

Now this output may or may not be your desired output depending on where you want to use the code 
you may be wondering why this happens when you have not specified python to add a new line, its due to the fact that print function add new line character at the end of the output by default so if you doesnot want that to happen add end="" for the output line end with a empty string or nothing. likewise use end="/t" for tab end="." to end the print statement with a period and so on.

ProTip 
use

```
print()
```

when ever you want a new line in or out of a loop